# RNN(GRU) initial memory(hidden state) when testing the real data

Tags: pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I try to use the Pytorch to learn the RNN(GRU).
I already known the forward process.
But I am confuse about testing real data after I finish training process.

Suppose I have a min-batch data which dimension is
`(40, 6, 15)=(seq_len, batch_size, word_vec_size)`.

Suppose define a single-direction GRU layer with hidden state size is 7 and layer is 1(no stack).

[image]

[image]

Do forward, I need to initialize a hidden state.

My question is when I test a real data, how do I determine initial hidden state?

If randomly determine, input same data, it probably get the different output.

I don't known my concept is right or not.

Thank you.

Comment: Well, how do you initialize in training? You also need to initialize it at the start of the sequence right?

Comment: Well...the initial hidden state depend on batch size, but for each data in the batch, they use the different initial hidden state, that my question.

Comment: Typically zero is used as the initial state -- if "they" use a different approach that depends on what their approach is.